# .NET Core 3 - my Area tag is not being recognised

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Hopefully there's something incredibly obvious I'm missing, but I've been at this a day so far with absolutely no luck - I've searched through 10+ Area tutorials to see if I can spot anything, but to no avail.

Here's my folder layout:

[image]

And endpoint routing:

[image]

(also tried):

[image]

and Controller:

[image]

and View:

[image]

Yet, with whatever I've tried, I'm always getting this in the HTML generation...

[image]

Note the ?area=Admin in the form.

Surely I'm doing everything right?! I've done this a million times in .NET MVC + .NET Core 2.x

Comment: Just to confirm which .net core is this? Title says 3, question says 2.

Comment: This is definitely 3, where does it say 2? I can change it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the "I've done this a million times"

Comment: No probs, thought so! :)

Comment: Is it just a missing 'areas' where you've got 'defaultArea' in the mapping section?

Comment: To be honest, I've even tried  endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                "admin",
                "admin",
                "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); and that's not worked too - it's absolutely baffling!

Comment: Silly question: have you restarted visual studio just to make sure it's not just some weird VS caching issue?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately, tried on 2 seperate machines just in case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not manage to reproduce the error. However, I have managed to create the example which works. Steps to create the [MWE](https://bitbucket.org/kasptom/dotnet-mvc-areas-stack/src/master/)

---

**tl;dr** (if won't work read all :D ):

Look at the 4th point. It seems that the specified name of the root folder of your areas is incorrect. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapareacontrollerroute?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

---

1) `dotnet new mvc`

2) Install the latest Aspnetboilerplate
`dotnet add package Abp.AspNetCore --version 5.0.0`

3) Create the `Areas\Admin\` directories with `Views` and `Controllers` (like on your screenshots)

4) Set up the routing (this may be the crucial part) in the `Startup.cs`:

```cs
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                                  name: "areas",
                                  areaName: "Admin",
                                  pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

5) `Areas\Admin\Controllers\BankHolidaysController.cs`

```cs
using System;
using Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace dotnet_mvc_areas_stack.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]

    public class BankHolidaysController : AbpController
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

6) `Areas\Views\BankHolidays\Create.cshtml` with the (degenerated :) ) form

```html
<p> This is index page of area </p>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="/Admin/BankHolidays/Create">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

7) `Create.cshtml` next to it

```html
<div>Created</div>
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a hero - let me see if I can get this working!

Comment: Definitely seems to be something in the aspnetboilerplate solution that's causing this, I've just used everything you've highlighted, word for word and still no luck! I'm going to accept your answer as it's basically making me create the solution again as I know it *can* work.

Comment: Thanks, as a bonus: here is the [MWE](https://bitbucket.org/kasptom/dotnet-mvc-areas-stack/src/master/)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you - just for the record, it's the aspnetboilerplate template that's broken from their website (not sure anyone has picked it up yet somehow). Downloaded a fresh copy of it, tried to add an Area straight away without touching anything else... fails just the same.

Comment: And the .NET Core 2.2 version works - so, ye, the framework's messed up in 3.0.

Comment: Which version of Abp.AspNetCore do you use? I've used 5.0.0 version with .NET Core 3.0.101 in [the example](https://bitbucket.org/kasptom/dotnet-mvc-areas-stack/src/master/dotnet-mvc-areas-stack.csproj)